# Do other EU countries have an equivalent of Germany's portal for foreign students?

Tags: europe, visa

The German government runs a portal, https://myguide.de, that allows prospective foreign university students to search for undergraduate and graduate degree programs offered by German universities. It allows filtering by several categories -- full-time vs. part-time, location, language of instruction, cost, etc.,.

Does any other European country have a **government-run** portal of this type? I know of a couple general, commercially run portals, but they tend to focus on overpriced degrees at private (or even for-profit) universities which, I assume, pay to have their incredibly spammy names listed, whereas I'm mostly interested in established public institutions with credible names and physical ties to their communities of origin.

Answer (score 1):

Sweden has [Studera.nu](https://www.studera.nu), which provides an introduction to Swedish higher education. Its Swedish version has such a search function, but I was only able to find the corresponding search function in English at the application site [Universityadmissions.se](https://www.universityadmissions.se). The corresponding application site in Swedish is [Antagning.se](https://www.antagning.se/). There are indeed search filters for language, study pace etc. The search results include information about the tuition fee (only applicable to non-EU/EEA citizens), but I don't think you can use cost as a filtering criterion. Note that you would generally apply to a university through one of these central portals, rather than through some system managed by the individual universities. The sites are run by The Swedish Council for Higher Education (Universitets- och högskolerådet), which is a government agency.

Answer (score 1):

In France there’s [Campus France](https://www.campusfrance.org/en), which is Government run, has the features you mentioned plus various explanations of the french higher education system (as well as things like visas, student housing, etc)